# What is the islamic view on profit received from a Profit and loss bank account?

Tags: banking

Is it a sin to receive profit from a profit and loss bank account? I heard that profit earned from one's bank account is haram. But how would this change if the person also incurs a loss in case the bank suffers a loss?

Comment: I've never heard of such a bank account.  Can you give me a link to such a bank?

Comment: Its called a PLS savings account http://www.soneribank.com/pls-savings

Comment: I can't provide you with a detailed answer at the moment using authentic sources.  So I will just give you an overview here.  Islamically, there is nothing wrong with profit and loss as long as where you have your money invests money in halaal companies.  So theoretically, a profit and loss savings account is absolutely fine.  All you have to do is find out where they invest the money.  If they only invest in halaal companies, then any profits and losses you end up with will be halaal too.  I'm sure someone else will give  you a much more details answer, if not, I will try later God willing.

Answer (score 1):

assalaamualaikum

look it has reached a point in todays society where money is the basis of everywhere we go, just like in the hadeeth of Rasool Allah (SAW). Interest is absolutely haraam, as allah says so in the quran, He has made trade halaal and interest haraam. Even in islamic banking systems, they still make profits and losses, but they have different methods which are halaal. For example, if you were to buy a house and borrowed money from a normal bank, they would lend you say $500 000, but when you repay it monethy, they add interest to it. If however you go to an Islamic bank to buy the same house, they would by it for you, then sell it to you at a higher price. This is different to the normal bank's way, as they now own the house and are just selling it back to you for a higher price, so this is trade, and that is what is halaal. In all honesty you should try to avoid interaction withthose banks altogether, because we know they deal in a haraam way, so my advice is just to leave that bank and join an Islamic one, as it is the best thing anyone can do for the sake of Allah SWT

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum...
you mean the bank invests in something and disseminates the profit/loss it incurs among its customers then it's fine and acceptable, it's analogous to investing in a business.

But if it's a savings account you're talking about then usually interest rate is set considering the inflation rate of that country so it's fine but to be on safer side don't consume it.

But accounts like Recurring Deposits, Fixed Deposits etc. have more interest than savings, so they're not allowed..

May Allah guide us all.

Comment: And also only if the banks earn through Halal ways, then it is allowed. Not by investing in Haram businesses.

Answer (score -1):

I think interest is there when one party is safguarded while the other party is putted on chance either profit or loss